# The server tag is not well formed ImageUrl

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have class **appdata** in which there is method named **Skt_Img_Path** in this method i have defined the path of an image that i want to access in `asp:Image` controls `ImageUrl`

HTML Markup

```
<asp:Image ID="image1" runat="server" 
    ImageUrl="<%=appdata.Stk_Img_Path%><%# Eval("image_name") %>" 
    class="img-responsive col-lg-10" 
    onmouseover="document.images.main_pic.src='<%=appdata.Stk_Img_Path %><%# Eval("image_name") %>'" />
```

I am getting this error

> "The server tag is not well formed"

What could be done to solve this?

Comment: `ImageUrl='<%# appdata.Stk_Img_Path + Eval("image_name") %>'`; remove the `onmouseoverevent` and try again

Comment: Well, hint: look at it in a browser and look at what you are forming there.

Comment: why the downvotes? server tag is not well formed is something very hard to debug IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

A better way to write this code will be this

Markup

```
<asp:Image ID="image2" runat="server" 
    ImageUrl='<%# GetImagePath(Eval("image_name")) %>' 
    class="img-responsive col-lg-10" 
    onmouseover="document.images.main_pic.src=this.src" />
```

Please note the use of a small helper function `GetImagePath`. Define it in code-behind as

```
protected string GetImagePath(object imageName)
{
    // TO DO: null check and other fail safe methods
    return appdata.Stk_Img_Path + imageName.ToString();
}
```

Also as `ImageUrl` in `asp:Image` is rendered as `src` in an `img` tag, `onmouseover` all you need is to assign that `src` to the container's `src`